# To Show different color to view on button click in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, view

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNmwg.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRreu.png)i'm Working on a view i have successfully shown the first color which is fixed i want another color to appear while on click of button. i have worked on dice and the total sum of two dice are showing . i want that whichever total number is coming it shows in the view as shown in image and that color changes.

```
   this.state={
  // This is our Default number value
  NumberHolder : 1,
  NumberHold : 1,
  sum: 0,
  }
  }

   GenerateRandomNumber = () => {
   let RandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
   let RandomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1 ;
   let sum = RandomNumber + RandomNumber1;

    this.setState({
    NumberHolder : RandomNumber,
    NumberHold : RandomNumber1,
    sum
     });
     }

    getDice(diceNum) {
    let diceSource = require(`./images/dice1.png`)
    if (diceNum === 2) {
    diceSource = require(`./images/dice2.png`)
    } else if (diceNum === 3) {
    diceSource = require(`./images/dice3.png`)
    } else if (diceNum === 4) {
    diceSource = require(`./images/dice4.png`)
    } else if (diceNum === 5) {
    diceSource = require(`./images/dice5.png`)
    } else if (diceNum === 6) {
    diceSource = require(`./images/dice6.png`)
     } else {
    diceSource = require(`./images/dice1.png`)
    }
     return (
    <Image style={styles.dice}source={diceSource} />
     )
     }

     render() {
    // this is just for the demo purposes
   const imageSize = this.state.NumberHolder * 50


    return (
   <View style={styles.MainContainer} >


   <View style={{ position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 20,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    marginRight:30,
    }}>
   <View style={{backgroundColor: '#006400'}}>
    <View style={{    position: 'absolute',
   top: 0,
   left: 20,
   width: 50,
   height: 50,
   marginLeft:40,

   backgroundColor: '#006400'}}>

        <Text style={{justifyContent: 'center',flex: 1,textAlign: 
    'center',
   marginTop:10,
   color: '#ffffff',
     alignItems: 'center'}}>
          1
        </Text>
    </View>


    <View style={{    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 20,
    width: 50,
     height: 50,
     marginLeft:90,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#000000',
     backgroundColor: '#006400'}}>

        <Text style={{justifyContent: 'center',flex: 1,textAlign: 
    'center',
    marginTop:10,
    color: '#ffffff',
     alignItems: 'center'}}>
          2
        </Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 20,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    marginLeft:130,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#000000',

    backgroundColor: '#006400'}}>

        <Text style={{justifyContent: 'center',flex: 1,textAlign: 
       'center',
    marginTop:10,
    color: '#ffffff',
     alignItems: 'center'}}>
          3
        </Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{    position: 'absolute',
     top: 0,
     left: 20,
      width: 50,
     height: 50,
     marginLeft:170,
     borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: '#000000',
      backgroundColor: '#006400'}}>

     <Text style={{justifyContent: 'center',flex: 1,textAlign: 'center',
     marginTop:10,
     color: '#ffffff',
     alignItems: 'center'}}>
          4
        </Text>
     </View>
     <View style={{    position: 'absolute',
      top: 0,
      left: 20,
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      marginLeft:210,
      borderWidth: 1,
       borderColor: '#000000',
       backgroundColor: '#006400'}}>

        <Text style={{justifyContent: 'center',flex: 1,textAlign: 
      'center',
      marginTop:10,
      color: '#ffffff',
      alignItems: 'center'}}>
          5
        </Text>
     </View>
    <View style={{    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 20,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    marginLeft:260,
    backgroundColor: '#006400'}}>

        <Text style={{justifyContent: 'center',flex: 1,textAlign: 
    'center',
   marginTop:10,
   color: '#ffffff',
   alignItems: 'center'}}>
          6
        </Text>
    </View>
    </View>
    </View>
    <View
     style={{
   borderBottomWidth: 2,
   borderBottomColor: 'black',
   width: 270,
   marginLeft:18,
   marginBottom:340,
   }}
   />

    <View style={{    position: 'absolute',
   top: 0,
   left: 20,
   width: 50,
   height: 50,
   marginLeft:40,
   marginTop:1
   }}>
    <View style={{    position: 'absolute',
  top: 0,
  left: 20,
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  borderWidth: 1,
  borderColor: '#000000',
  marginTop:50,
  backgroundColor: '#006400'}}>

        <Text style={{justifyContent: 'center',flex: 1,textAlign: 
    'center',
    marginTop:10,
    color: '#ffffff',
     alignItems: 'center'}}>
          7
        </Text>
    </View>

    </View>

    <Button style={{marginTop:40}}  title="Roll again" onPress= 
     {this.GenerateRandomNumber} />
     </View>
```

I want that whenever the total number is shown it shows in the view with different color.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9U2ah.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the color of a single view, based of a state variable, you just need to put a condition on the style prop.

For example:

```
    <View style={{    position: 'absolute',
   top: 0,
   left: 20,
   width: 50,
   height: 50,
   marginLeft:40,

   backgroundColor: this.state.sum===1?"red":'#006400'}}>

        <Text style={{justifyContent: 'center',flex: 1,textAlign: 
    'center',
   marginTop:10,
   color: '#ffffff',
     alignItems: 'center'}}>
          1
        </Text>
    </View>
```

As you have rendered them like that you have to do it on every View.

I would suggest to cycle trough a function to create a  as they are all the same expect for the number.

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@charliexyz/fascinated-raspberries plzz check this i have one text in which sum of the two dice coming i want that sum to show in the upper view as shown in image

Comment: the snack does not work, what are you trying to achieve? What color are you trying to change?

Comment: have you seen the image in the discription when i'm clicking on the roll again button i'm getting the sum of two dice. now i want to show that number in the upper view in green when that number came it becomes red

Comment: i want this i want that number to display and get highlight by red color

Comment: So you want to change the color of the text that displays the number "5" in the image?

Comment: yes, i particular text which will appear in the sum text

Comment: TypeError: TypeError: this.getColor is not a function. (In 'this.getColor()', 'this.getColor' is undefined)

This error is located at:

Comment: You need to define this.getColor() based off how you want it to work, i've created an example but you have to change it for your code

Comment: can you suggest what should i add like i want to change the colour

Comment: What do you mean? to change the color instead of return "red" return another color. Check my second edit

Comment: plzz check the updated image this is what i'm getting i'm getting sum in all the text.

Comment: i want to highlight that view only in which sum number is coming

Comment: Alright, finally i've understand what you want to accomplish. Do you want to change also the background color or only the single number color?

Comment: plzz check the new image this is what i want to accomplish

Comment: Did you try my new answer?

Comment: but your logic is correct i don't know it's not showing

Answer (score 0):

```
toggleColor = () => {
  this.setState(p => {
    return {
      flag: !p.flag
    }
  })
}

render() {
  let color = 'red'
  if (flag) { // you can change this condition to anything
    color = 'green'
  } else {
    color = 'red'
  }
  return (
    <View style={{backgroundColor:color}}></View>
  )
}
```

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@charliexyz/fascinated-raspberries plzz check this i have one text in which sum of the two dice coming i want that sum to show in the upper view as shown in image